# Factoring Question.

Tags: factoring

I am so confused.. i need to factor out $e^t$ from the following equation $2{e^2}^ty''-6e^ty'+8y=2e^t+2{e^2}^tt$ i know in fact that the answer is $y''-4y'+4y=t{e^2}^t+e^t$ but i always end up with something different. Here's my try

(1) -> $2e^t(e^ty''-3y')+8y=2e^t(1+e^tt)$
(2) -> $e^ty''-3y'+8y=1+e^tt$
I am doing something wrong... please help.

Comment: Note that $e^{2^t} \neq e^{2t}$, so you cannot factor $e^t$ out of the term $e^{2^t}$.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. My mistake its e^(2t)

Comment: Please edit the question accordingly, which you can do by using the edit button at the bottom of your post.